# A question about the Riemann Mapping Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

let $G$ be a simply connected open set and properly contained in $\mathbb{C}$. Fix $a \in G$, $b \in \mathbb{D}$ and $\alpha \in [0, 2 \pi]$. prove that there is a unique analytic bijection $f: G \to \mathbb{D}$ such that $f(a)=b$ and arg$(f'(a)) = \alpha$.

This is a question adapted from Conway's book "Functions of one Complex Variable I" on page 163 exercise #7. There we have $f(a) = 0$ and $f'(a) > 0$ for some $a \in G$. I would like to solve this same question but with these adaptations that $f(a)=b$ and arg $(f'(a)) = \alpha$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: You can start by any $F:G\to\mathbb{D}$ given by Riemann. Next you can move around $F(a)$ by composing $F$ with automorphisms of the disc $z\mapsto \frac{z-\alpha}{1-\overline{\alpha}z}$, with $|\alpha|<1$. Choose $\alpha$ such that $F(a)$ gets mapped to $b$ and the other condition.

Comment: For the uniqueness, look at two functions $f,g$ satisfying those properties. Look at $f\circ g^{-1}:\mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{D}$. Apply [Schwarz's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma). Maybe for convenience, conjugate $\phi^{-1}\circ f\circ g^{-1}\circ \phi$ with an automorphim from above such that $0\mapsto 0$.